# Update data in SQL Server Express 2008 using VB 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want your help with VB 2010 (Visual Studio 2010).
Here is the code snippet

`objCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE tblCustomers SET weight= @weight, height= @height WHERE id=@id "`

What i want to do is the following:

I have a form and i want,by clicking the appropriate button, to update the height and weight values which have the specified primary key 'id'.

The primary key 'id' is of type IDENTITY.The problem is that the above code does not work. It says Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

Any help is appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `@id`,`@weight`,and `@height` parameters to the parameters list of your `objCommand`

```
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParamerter("@Id",id))
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParamerter("@weight",weight))
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParamerter("@height",height))
objCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE tblCustomers SET weight= @weight, height= @height WHERE id=@id"
objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

where the values(second parameter of `SqlParameter` constructor) of your parameters come from your form.

Note you should load the value of `@Id` into the form. I don't know what is the data you have loaded but I think there is some control contains the `ID` value. You should read it back and pass it into your command paramerters

Comment: Thanks Amir for your quick reply.It helped me a lot!